# Implement Gremlin / Janusgraph Websocket Client in Javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket, gremlin, janusgraph

I need to implement a connection to a Janusgraph (v0.2) / Gremlin (v3.2.6) via javascript. However, I see that the lowest version of gremlin-javascript is 3.2.8, and even so, it does not have sasl authentication features.

Hence, how can I implement a simple gremlin (v3.2.6) / janusgraph (v0.2) client using native WebSocket libraries in javascript with plain sasl authentication?

^*I tried using basic authentication for WebSocket but it didn't appear to work

Answer (score 3):

SASL support for Gremlin in Javascript became a feature at 3.2.10, 3.3.4, and 3.4.0 on [TINKERPOP-1977](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1977). Since SASL support went into core at 3.1.3 and 3.2.1 on [TINKERPOP-1263](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1263) (with [TINKERPOP-1600](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1600) also in place by 3.2.4), I would think JansuGraph in fine shape to be compatible. I would try 3.2.10 as it should be largely compatible with the Gremlin 3.2.6. Of course, the 3.2.x line of code has not been maintained in some time so an upgrade to JanusGraph might be a better choice if you really need to use Gremlin and Javascript.